# finding the minimum between 3 numbers

Tags: matlab, minimum

How can I find the smallest number among three that is non zero.

I tried introducing a very small number `eps = 1e-6` (my numbers are either zero or clearly larger than eps) and doing tests between min(x,eps), min(y,eps) etc. I didn't get anything. Is there a way to do that with a function?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do. Did you try `min(x, min(y, z))`?

Comment: yes this one doesn't work because when y=0 for instance, the result is zero (all coefficients are positive) but I want to keep the smallest strictly positive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
numbers = [1 3 4 -2 1 0];
answer = min(numbers(numbers>0));

answer == 1
```

Answer (score 5):

If the numbers are all stored in a vector `x` you could do the following:

```
x = [1 0 2 0 3 0 4];
y = min(x(x>0));
```

This is based on your statement that

> numbers are either zero or clearly larger than `eps`

If you mean larger in *magnitude* and you want to accept non-zero negative values you could use:

```
x = [1 0 -2 0 3 0 4];
y = min(x(x~=0));
```

Note that this will return the *most negative* number when negative numbers are present, rather than the number with the smallest non-zero magnitude.  To get the number with the smallest non-zero magnitude, you could use:

```
x = [1 0 -2 0 3 0 4];
xnonzero = x(x~=0);
[~,idx] = min(abs(xnonzero));
y = xnonzero(idx);
```

It doesn't seem very elegant.  There is probably a more direct way.

Comment: `builtin('_paren',x(x~=0),abs(x(x~=0)) == min(abs(x(x~=0))))` or `y = x(x~=0); ans = y(abs(y) == min(abs(y)));`

Comment: @Frederick  I'm not sure whether to respond "Cool!" or "Yuck!"

Comment: @Frederick +1 for `y = x(x~=0); ans = y(abs(y) == min(abs(y)));` You can keep the first one you posted. :)

Comment: I wish Mathworks would come out with a cleaner syntax to pull off the `builtin('_paren', ... )`.  I would use something like that all the time *if it was readable*.

Comment: yes - i agree - something like `foo(1)(2)` works in python (of course, right?), and it's really helpful

Comment: @nispio - I use it all the time anyway.  :D